# Inverse Fourier transformation of $\frac{1}{(1+w^2)^2}$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I have tried to crack this via basic definition, but I am unable to solve the integral:
$$\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+w^2)^2} e^{-iwx} dw  $$
Kindly guide me a bit.
Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid doing the integral if you know the Fourier transform of $1/(1+w^2)$
(which is $\pi e^{-|x|}$) and recall that the Fourier transform converts multiplication
into convolution.

Therefore, for $g(x)=e^{-|x|}$,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-iwx}\,dw}{(1+w^2)^2}
=g*g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(y)g(x-y)\,dy
=\pi^2\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp(-|y|-|x-y|)\,dy.$$
One can split this into three integrals over intervals where $-|y|-|x-y|$
is linear on each.